Nucleophilic attack on Double bond carbon vs Carbonyl group in conjugated Aldehyde
I came across a question in which aldol condenstation is to be performed first and than a nucleophilic addition with CN- , I thought it will attack the carbonyl carbon as it is more electrophilic , the solution shows nucleophilic attack rather on the pi bond carbon , is it due to conjugation and steric reasons or I'm  missing something? . Please help me with an explanation and Also then in what cases should the C=C attack be preferred as compared to that on Carbonyl Carbon?




In alpha-beta unsaturated carbonyl compounds some reagents show 1,4 addition
(conjugate addition) while some show normal 1,2 addition.

CN- shows 1,4 addition with aldehydes and 1,2 addition with ketones

RMgX, RLi, NaBH4, LiAlH4, etc show 1,2 addition

R2CuLi, R2Cd, HBr, active methyl group, etc show 1,4 addition

In case of AMG it is called michael addition


